# How to apply numeric functions to non-numerics in loops

Tags: r, loops

I want to create a loop where it puts an asterisks on the dataframe number with the largest outlier until the dis > 0.1 criteria is met. Example: ***125**

Unfortunately the loop breaks down after the first conversion as I get the following error:
**Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables.** I realize this error is happening because the ***125** is non-numeric so can't use the max or min functions, but how to get around this?

The dataset will contain NA values as well, as seen below.

Any help is very much appreciated

```
Example of desired Output:
Name    Result1    Name2    Result2 
A       80         BB       113 
A       NA         BB       110 
B       100        BB       NA  
B       *75        BB       105 
B       95         BB       *125
```

Code:

```
# convert Result1 and Result2 columns to numeric

data[, c("Result1","Result2")] <- lapply(data[, c("Result1","Result2")], as.character)
data[, c("Result1","Result2")] <- lapply(data[, c("Result1","Result2")], as.numeric)


# process data

large  <- max(data[c(2,4)],na.rm = TRUE)
small <- min(data[c(2,4)],na.rm = TRUE)
dis <- (large - small)/((large + small)/2)
x1 <- max(data[c(2,4)], na.rm = TRUE)
x2 <- min(data[c(2,4)], na.rm = TRUE)


# loop


while (dis > 0.1) {

   if ((large - a2) > (a2- small)){
    data[c(2,4)] <- unlist(lapply(data[c(2,4)],gsub, pattern =  x1, replacement = paste0("*", max(data[c(2,4)], na.rm = TRUE)), data[c(2,4)]), use.names=FALSE)
  } else {
    data[c(2,4)] <- unlist(lapply(data[c(2,4)],gsub, pattern =  x2, replacement = paste0("*", min(data[c(2,4)], na.rm = TRUE)), data[c(2,4)]), use.names=FALSE)
  }

  large <- max(data[c(2,4)],na.rm = TRUE)
  small <- min(data[c(2,4)],na.rm = TRUE)
  dis <- (large - small)/((large + small)/2)
  data
}
```

Comment: The asterisk should be in a separate column. Then this column could stay numeric which has huge advantages.

Comment: That's true, I thought about that but there will be instances where the dis > 0.1 criteria is met so no need to add any asterisks so it might look weird, since some tables have an extra column and some not

Answer (score 0):

We could remove the `*` and then convert to `numeric`

```
nm1 <- grep('^Result', names(data), value = TRUE)
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[nm1], function(x) 
        as.numeric(sub("*", "", x, fixed = TRUE))
```

The `max`, `min` works on vectors and not on a `data.frame`.  So, we can loop over the `data.frame` columns and get the `max`, `min`

```
large <- sapply(df1[nm1], max, na.rm = TRUE)
small <- sapply(df1[nm1], min, na.rm = TRUE)
dis <- (large - small)/((large + small)/2)
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('Result'), ~ as.numeric(str_remove(., fixed('*'))))) %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('Result'), list(max = ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE), min = ~ min(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```